# DataGridView get row values

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to get the cell values of the row that I clicked.

here's my code..

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        txtFullName.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtUsername.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtPassword.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    }
```

works fine.. but it doesn't work when I click on the row(left side of the UserID) and on user id column... it also gives me an error when I click on the column header. how can I fix that error and I want it to also click on row and userid column.

[image]

Comment: `Cells[0]` *is* the UserID... isn't it? `Cells[1]` should be the Full Name?

Comment: @Ben Yes it is.. I was just trying to get the userid... my problem is when I click on UserID column and on row(left side of the userid) doesn't give me anything... and when I click on the clomun header it gives me an error....

Comment: For clicking of the Row Header, use the RowHeaderMouseClick event.  For the error on clicking the column header, check that e.RowIndex is not -1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the wrong event: Try this

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            var val = this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex,  e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `SelectionChanged` eventhandler and `CurrentRow` property of the `DataGridView`, which were designed exactly for your purposes

```
void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView temp = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (temp.CurrentRow == null)
        return; //Or clear your TextBoxes
    txtFullName.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    txtUsername.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    txtPassword.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}
```

And set `SelectionMode` to the `FullRowSelection`

```
this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

Comment: Thank you! I just dont understand when the current row is going to be "null"

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error caused on clicking column headers, you have to check if `e.RowIndex` is 0 or more:

```
void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1) { return; }
    txtFullName.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    txtUsername.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    txtPassword.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}
```

To set an event on clicking row headers, you have to register an event handler to `RowHeaderMouseClick` event.

```
dataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseClick += dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick;
```